# flutter_inapp_purchase Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=825

Tags: flutter

Version of flutter_inapp_purchase

flutter_inapp_purchase: ^5.2.0

Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)

IOS

Expected behavior

success callback

Actual behavior

error callback

Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)

Real Device

Steps to reproduce the behavior
I encountered some problems. On my iPhone real machine, the sandbox account was used, and the payment was not successful. After reporting some errors, I couldn't solve it. Someone encountered me wrong and told the solution?

image
<SKPaymentQueue: 0x2830e8d30>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=825 "No transactions in response" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No transactions in response}
Purchase Failed !!
flutter: purchase-error: responseCode: null, debugMessage: SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed, code: E_UNKNOWN, message: An unknown or unexpected error has occured. Please try again later.